# Error when transferring table via VBA in Access

Tags: ms-access

When I run this, I get run time error 3027: "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only."

```vb
Private Sub Export_Run()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    
    If fd.Show = True Then
        If Format(fd.SelectedItems(1)) <> vbNullString Then
            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Export_tbl", fd.SelectedItems(1), False
        End If
    End If    
End Sub
```

The table I'm trying to export (Export_tbl) exists and is editable (not read only), and I can manually export it without issue. I'm guessing this may be an issue with the machine I'm on, with permissions or something? Or am I using the filedialog reference incorrectly? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The destination file may be open, e.g. in Excel. If this is the case, then close Excel and you will be able to export.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes good call, I didn't check that but in this case it doesn't seem to be the problem...

Comment: Try to delete the file before exporting: `If Dir(FileToDelete) <> "" Then Kill FileToDelete End If`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I failed to properly assign a full file name for the table being exported---you need to include the file path, name, AND extension (at least in this case, since I'm trying to export as text/CSV). The following worked:

```
Private Sub Export_Run()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    If fd.Show = True Then
        If Format(fd.SelectedItems(1)) <> vbNullString Then
            thename = fd.SelectedItems(1) & ".csv"
            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Export_tbl", thename, False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```